# Can a Drupal Site Administrator view contents of settings.php or some other file in file system?

Tags: 8

We are using Drupal 8.6.3.

I want to store some configuration in file system (in settings.php or some other file outside Web Root).

Can a Drupal Site Administrator view that configuration?

What parts of settings.php file can be viewed by a Drupal Site Administrator?

Answer (score 0):

For brevity, it helps to think about this question in terms of ***roles/permissions*** (since "site admin" is an overloaded term):

*Does the ____ role have an escalated permission to:*

- Write arbitrary files to the server?
- Execute arbitrary code on the server?

If the first/second answer is "Yes," the answer would be:

*____ role could probably come up with a clever way to read the entire contents of settings.php by injecting/running arbitrary code.*

Generally, Drupal core tries to signal these potentially dangerous permissions with this warning:

> Warning: Give to trusted roles only; this permission has security implications.

However, there are many contrib modules out there that could have exploits (some known, some not) so you'll always have to take [pro-active security steps](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:Principle) like the *principle of least privilege* (if a role doesn't need a privilege to do the job, don't give it to them).

This also applies to your whole system (DB, web server, etc.), not just Drupal.

Comment: Also a site admin. may be able to _view_ variables that is stored statically in $conf if they have permission to view the user interface that configures that variable.